# Finding number of common elements between different columns of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has almost 70-80 columns. Each column consists of 100-150 rows in which values are stored as strings.

I would like to find, for each column, what is the number of common elements present in the rest of the columns of the DataFrame.

For example: say I have a dataframe like:

```
       0      1      2        3
0    cat     ox   bull    horse
1   lion    dog    cat    zebra
2   bull     ox  horse    tiger
3  horse  eagle   bull  giraffe
```

Starting with first column, I need answer as 2,3 as 2 seems to have most number of common elements with the column 0 after that column 3 as it has comparatively less number of common elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can build something like below. You can leverage set().intersection() to find the intersection between list. You need to loop one column with other columns.

You would Notice that I changed the values of df columns into a list in order to use a set

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['cat','lion','bull','horse'], 'B': ['ox','dog','ox','eagle'],
                   'C': ['bull','cat','horse','bull'],'D': ['horse','zebra','tiger','giraffe']})

df_out = pd.DataFrame()

for col in df.columns:
    # making a list of all column which has to be compared with col 
    other_col = [x for x in df.columns if x!=col]
    for oCol in other_col:
        #using a set we can find a intersection between 2 list and count them
        count = len(set(df[col].values.tolist()).intersection(df[oCol].values.tolist()))
        #storing all count with their respective column in separate df
        df_out = df_out.append([(col,oCol,count)],sort=True,ignore_index=True)


df_out.columns = ['Column','Comparison','Count']

df_out.sort_values(by=['Column','Count'],ascending=[True,False],inplace=True)
```

Output would look something like this:

`Column Comparison  Count
1   A   C   3
2   A   D   1
0   A   B   0
3   B   A   0
4   B   C   0
5   B   D   0
6   C   A   3
8   C   D   1
7   C   B   0
9   D   A   1
11  D   C   1
10  D   B   0`